# Prettier stopped working in VS Code - error "No configuration provided"

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using Prettier in Visual Studio Code, but it's suddenly stopped working for .scss files.

I haven't changed any settings, and I have checked my Settings and all seems to be ok.

I am getting a "Prettier: X" in the bottom toolbar

[image]
  
and when this is clicked on I get the error message:

```
No configuration provided for /*/_file.scss
```

I've never added any configuration, it "just worked" - any ideas as to what I can try to get it working?

Comment: Do you find any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I found that I could get it to work by disabling "Stylelint integration" in the settings, found under Extensions > Prettier

Otherwise, you'll need to create a stylelint config file for each project. This obviously isn't ideal for every instance (probably Prettier should provide the option to bypass Stylelint if no config was found).

The following inks might be helpful to get you going with a stylelint config, if that's the direction you'd like to go in:

- https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration/
- https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard